# CSS - How can I display two different posts next to each other?

Tags: html, css, ejs

Currently, If I have two posts they position them self under/above one and other, but I want them to display next to each other, how can I go about doing that, also I would highly appreciate if someone could just have a general look into my CSS code, what is basically good and bad there :=D Big Thanks

admin.css

```css
.grid {
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
}

.grid .post {
    border: 4px dashed #207420;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
}
```

posts.ejs

```html
<%- include("../includes/head.ejs") %>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/admin.css">
</head>

<body>
    <%- include("../includes/navigation.ejs", ) %>
    <main>
        <% if (posts.length > 0) { %>

        <% for (let post of posts) { %>

        <div class="grid">
            <article class="post">
                <h1><%=post.title%></h1>
                <p><%=post.description%></p>
                <a href="/post/<%=post._id%>">See Post</a>
            </article>
        </div>

        <% } %>
        <%  } else { %>

        <h1>No Posts Found</h1>
        <% } %>
    </main>

    <%- include("../includes/footer.ejs") %>
```

Comment: At first glance, it seems that each `.post` is inside its own `.grid`. It might help to put *all* posts inside the grid. Is it possible to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the rendered HTML instead of the templating code?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [grid layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout) or a [flex layou](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex)t to achieve this.

**Using Grid**

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 1em;
}

.post {
  height: 200px;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="post"></div>
  <div class="post"></div>
</div>
```

**Using Flexbox**

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
}

.post {
  height: 200px;
  background: #ccc;
}

.flex .post {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.flex .post:nth-child(2) {
  margin-left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="post"></div>
  <div class="post"></div>
</div>
```

There is also other methods like using Floats, but grids and flexboxes would be more flexible.

Comment: The OP is using flexbox: `.grid { display: flex; ... `

Comment: @TigerAbrodi which approach are you using? `grid` or `flex` ?

Comment: Well as you can see my friend, I'm trying to use flex, i also tried grid but it did not go well, a mate of mine sent me a grid tutorial from coding tech on yt, but here it is going good the only PROBLEM i have now is that the posts to display next to each other, but they do not have any space between one and other, how would i go about that, i tried it with justify content but it did not work well.

Comment: its still not clear to me what you are trying other than to get elements side by side. Can you share any screenshots?